# Django delete error message

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

i have two models.
when i try delete contact recevied error

```
Exception Value:    

("Cannot delete some instances of model 'GuestContact' because they are referenced through a protected foreign key: 'Reservation.res_company'", <QuerySet [<Reservation: Reservation object>, <Reservation: Reservation object>]>)
```

i dont' want see django error page. i want send information " this record can't be delete, but this contact is used in reservation"

can you help me ?

regards

Comment: could you post the view??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `delete()` in a `try:except` and return a response with a custom error message,

```
from django.db.models import ProtectedError

try:
    instance.delete()
except ProtectedError:
    error_message = "This object can't be deleted!!"
    return JsonResponse(error_message)
```

Comment: How do you display the `foreignkey` that is causing the `on_delete` error in the response?

Comment: @alias51 - Did you get a solution?

Comment: did you try `vars(instance)` before deleting it?

Answer (score 2):

Hi you need to use exception `ProtectedError`

```
try:
    #DELETE STUFF
except ProtectedError:
    #CUSTOM MESSAGE
```

> Raised to prevent deletion of referenced objects when using
>   django.db.models.PROTECT. models.ProtectedError is a subclass of
>   IntegrityError.

doc here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.11/ref/exceptions/#django.db.models.ProtectedError

Comment: How do you display the `foreignkey` that is causing the `on_delete` error in the response?